# Is it possible to call the Apps Script Execution API via a jQuery `ajax` method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script-api

Is it possible to call the Apps Script Execution API via a jQuery `ajax` method?

I am getting request failures using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{script_id}:run",
    data : {
        'function' : 'getProjects',
        'parameters : [token]'}
    },
    success : function(msg){
        alert('ajax success');
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('ajax fail');
    }
});
```

I am not sure that I am submitting the oauth2 token currently as part of the request body.

Comment: If you have the OAuth2 token, it needs to go in the `header` property of the settings object. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more information

Comment: Cheers this solved my issue